# Ember.js - rest adapter sends request to wrong url

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js

My models are defined as follows:

**server**

```
DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    databases: DS.hasMany('database', {async: true})
});
```

**database**

```
DS.Model.extend(BaseModelMixin, {
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    server: DS.belongsTo('server'),
    schemas: DS.hasMany('schema', {async: true})
});
```

And the router setup is as follows:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('servers', { path: '/' }, function() {
      this.resource('server', { path: '/servers/:serverid'}, function () {
          this.resource('databases', { path: '/databases' }, function () {
              this.resource('database', { path: '/:databaseid'}, function () {
                  this.resource('catalogues', { path: '/catalogues' });
                  this.resource('eventtriggers', { path: '/eventtriggers' });
                  this.resource('extensions', { path: '/extensions' });
                  this.resource('schemas', { path: '/schemas' }, function () {
                      this.resource('schema', { path: '/:schemaid' }, function () {
                          this.resource('new-table');

                          this.resource('tables', { path: '/tables' }, function () {
                              this.resource('table', { path: '/:tableid' });
                          });
                      });
                  });
                  this.resource('replication', { path: '/replication' });
              });
          });
      });
    });
});
```

In my application I have a menu that allows me to navigate between server and it's database. While doing that the `DS.RESTAdapter` sends request to mock server to retrieve the data. It should be sending requests to these urls:

`/api/servers`

`/api/servers/1`

`/api/servers/1/databases`

`/api/servers/1/databases/1`

It's sending requests to `/api/databases` url without prefixing it with a correct path. What can I do about that?

Comment: How is your router set up? This might be of some use - http://fromrailstoember.com/9-nested-routes-equals-nested-ui/

Comment: Don't know if that url will be of use for me. I found this: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/nested-urls-for-ember-datas-restadapter-proposal/5290/10 and it seems like there's some kind of debate on nested routes?

Comment: One of the core member teams has set up an example project for nested models. https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-data-nested-urls

Comment: It's year old and a year without a commit... Do you think it's still ok to use this?

Comment: Its been a while since Ive worked with ember and I know its production moves quite fast so I dont know. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to define an adapter. Take a look at this page in the Ember guide: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/models/the-rest-adapter/.

Without an adapter defined, it's looking for an api folder in your current domain.

Basically, you want to do something like this:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'https://api.example.com'
});
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

Here's a bit of my code from a current project using Ember-CLI (edited slightly). Maybe there's a nugget in here:

**Adapter:**

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://localhost:8080'
});
```

**Route:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('human', {'path': '/humans'}, function() {
    this.route('edit', {'path': ':human_id/edit'}, function() {
      this.route('remove', { path: 'remove' });
    });
    this.route('add');
  });
```

**Models:**

human

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  categories: DS.hasMany('category', {async: true}),
  groups: DS.hasMany('group', {async: true}),
  tags: DS.hasMany('tag', {async: true}),
  first_name: DS.attr('string'),
  last_name: DS.attr('string'),
  born: DS.attr()
});
```

category

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Comment: It's not that. I have a test adapter defined and generally everything is done right. The problem is (and that came up after a few hour research) that embers' restadapter doesn't support nested routes out of the box...

Comment: I use nested routes in my applications with no modifications. What version of Ember/Ember Data are you using? I noticed you're using BaseModelMixin, which I'm not familiar with. Also, the newest version of Ember uses "route" exclusively instead of "resource."

Comment: I'm using the newest of both, so ember 1.13.3 and ember-data 1.13.5 (wow, is that correct? I recently updated whole development environment and haven't noticed that ember-data version change). `BaseModelMixin` is my code and it provides some utility methods. It does not concern routing.

Comment: I changed routing to use `route` method but the application adapter still behaves the same way - it tries to send request to `/api/databases/1` instead of `/api/servers/1/databases/1`.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. When I get home, I'll check it and accept your answer if it works for me.